# Is there a better way to access values in a JSON file than a 'for' loop?

Tags: python, json, list, readlines

I have a JSON file which looks like this:

```
[{'data': [{'text': 'add '},
   {'text': 'Stani, stani Ibar vodo', 'entity': 'entity_name'},
   {'text': ' songs in '},
   {'text': 'my', 'entity': 'playlist_owner'},
   {'text': ' playlist '},
   {'text': 'música libre', 'entity': 'playlist'}]},
 {'data': [{'text': 'add this '},
   {'text': 'album', 'entity': 'music_item'},
   {'text': ' to '},
   {'text': 'my', 'entity': 'playlist_owner'},
   {'text': ' '},
   {'text': 'Blues', 'entity': 'playlist'},
   {'text': ' playlist'}]},
 {'data': [{'text': 'Add the '},
   {'text': 'tune', 'entity': 'music_item'},
   {'text': ' to the '},
   {'text': 'Rage Radio', 'entity': 'playlist'},
   {'text': ' playlist.'}]}]
```

I want to append the values in 'text' for each 'data' in this list.

I have tried the following:

```
lst = []

for item in data:
    p = item['data']
    p_st = ''
    for item_1 in p:
        p_st += item_1['text'] + ' '
    lst.append(p_st)

print(lst)

Out: ['add  Stani, stani Ibar vodo  songs in  my  playlist  música libre ', 'add this  album  to  my   Blues  playlist ', 'Add the  tune  to the  Rage Radio  playlist. ']
```

It works, but I am new to JSON and am wondering if there is a better way to do it? Some built-in methods or libraries for JSON maybe?

Comment: Your data may have come from a `json` file, but is no longer `json`. `for` loops seem appropriate here.

Comment: that will work but an iterator would be better, so you can use str.join -- search stackoverflow for "python flatten" (although this may be more of a stackreview question)

Comment: The builtin `json` module provides a method to parse the json file into a python dictionary, which you seem to have already used. Once you have the dictionary, the only way of operating over all elements of that dictionary is to use a loop. Why do you think this is not a good way to do this? What _specifically_ are you looking for when you say "better way"?

Comment: The only change I can think of is to use `str.join` to join the strings, so replace your inner loop with `p_st = ' '.join([item_1['text'].strip() for item_1 in p])`, but this still has a "loop" in the list comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works well for extracting the text values from the JSON data. However, if you want a more concise way to achieve the same result, you can use list comprehensions in Python, which can make your code shorter and more readable. Here's how you can do it:

**Using JSON module and list comprehensions**:

```
import json

data = [{'data': [{'text': 'add '}, {'text': 'Stani, stani Ibar vodo', 'entity': 'entity_name'}, {'text': ' songs in '}, {'text': 'my', 'entity': 'playlist_owner'}, {'text': ' playlist '}, {'text': 'música libre', 'entity': 'playlist'}]},
        {'data': [{'text': 'add this '}, {'text': 'album', 'entity': 'music_item'}, {'text': ' to '}, {'text': 'my', 'entity': 'playlist_owner'}, {'text': ' '}, {'text': 'Blues', 'entity': 'playlist'}, {'text': ' playlist'}]},
        {'data': [{'text': 'Add the '}, {'text': 'tune', 'entity': 'music_item'}, {'text': ' to the '}, {'text': 'Rage Radio', 'entity': 'playlist'}, {'text': ' playlist.'}]}]

text_values = [' '.join(item['text'] for item in entry['data']) for entry in data]

print(text_values)
```

**Using pandas**:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'data': [{'text': 'add '}, {'text': 'Stani, stani Ibar vodo', 'entity': 'entity_name'}, {'text': ' songs in '}, {'text': 'my', 'entity': 'playlist_owner'}, {'text': ' playlist '}, {'text': 'música libre', 'entity': 'playlist'}]},
        {'data': [{'text': 'add this '}, {'text': 'album', 'entity': 'music_item'}, {'text': ' to '}, {'text': 'my', 'entity': 'playlist_owner'}, {'text': ' '}, {'text': 'Blues', 'entity': 'playlist'}, {'text': ' playlist'}]},
        {'data': [{'text': 'Add the '}, {'text': 'tune', 'entity': 'music_item'}, {'text': ' to the '}, {'text': 'Rage Radio', 'entity': 'playlist'}, {'text': ' playlist.'}]}]

# Create a DataFrame from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Extract and join the 'text' values for each 'data' entry
text_values = df['data'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(item['text'] for item in x))

print(text_values.tolist())
```

The pandas approach is more suitable if you plan to perform additional data analysis or manipulation on your JSON data, as it provides a powerful and flexible way to work with structured data.

Answer (score 0):

There's no special JSON facility that will help here, because you've already *parsed* the JSON, and have plain old Python `dict`s and `list`s and `str`s (and no, the parsing process isn't modifiable in any trivial way to do what you want, this should be done after parsing).

That said, your code is non-idiomatic, and has some inefficiencies in it (ones that CPython *tries* to help with, but the optimization for repeated concatenation of `str` is brittle, non-portable, and still worse than doing it the right way with `str.join`). The improved code would look like this:

```
lst = [' '.join([item_1['text'] for item_1 in item['data']])
       for item in data]
print(lst)
```

That uses a list comprehension to produce the outer list, where each element produced is the space-separated concatenation of all the `'text'` values for that `item`'s `'data'`. The use of a listcomp for the outer part makes things a *little* faster (it's a microoptimization taking advantage of interpreter optimizations for listcomps, but it's not big-O improvement). The use of `' '.join` *is* a big-O algorithmic improvement though; repeated string concatenation is `O(n²)` (CPython optimizes it to almost `O(n)` *sometimes*, but not as well, and not reliably), while bulk concatenation via `' '.join` is guaranteed `O(n)`. If your data is only a small number of strings, as shown, the difference may be negligible, but the code is simpler and easier to read/maintain. If the data has *many* strings to concatenate, this may speed it up significantly.

Note: This does mean the concatenated string will not end with a space. Odds are you don't want that trailing space anyway, but you can always add it back if you really want; a single extra concatenation won't ruin big-O.

Comment: For the curious: As an implementation detail of CPython (that could change, but hasn't in years), passing the result of a listcomp to `str.join` is faster than passing a raw generator expression, because any iterable passed to it, aside from a `list` or `tuple`, is slurped to an internal `list` before the joining begins, so you pay the CPU overhead of the genexpr without saving anything on peak memory or temporary `list`s. `' '.join(item_1['text'] for item_1 in item['data'])` works fine, it's just a little slower.

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
with open(filename,'r+') as file:
    #open and load json file into dict
    file_data = json.load(file)
    #append new data to dict
    file_data[].append(new_data)
    #sets file's current position at offset
    file.seek(0)
    #convert back to json
    json.dump(file_data, file, indent = 4)
```

Comment: That's not even valid Python syntax... And it doesn't do remotely what the OP asked for even if the syntax were fixed.

Comment: This is not a working code. Please do write valid code.